# Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘selectr’ --Extracting data from web to R using rvest package

Tags: r

Hi i am getting an error while extracting the data from web to R using rvest package. i am using below link

```
library(rvest)

htmlpage<-html("http://www.glassdoor.com/GD/Reviews/IBM-India-Reviews-E602253_P2.htm?filter.employmentStatus=REGULAR&filter.employmentStatus=PART_TIME&filter.employmentStatus=UNKNOWN")

proshtml<-html_nodes(htmlpage,".pros")

pros<-html_text(proshtml)
pros=data.frame(pros)
```

Once link is copied from web then i run

```
proshtml<-html_nodes(htmlpage,".pros")
```

but below error is shown

```
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘selectr’
```

Can any one answer please so that i can extract the data i am using selector gadget for selecting the specific texts

Comment: Try `install.packages("selectr")` to install the missing package.

Comment: @MrFlick Should rvest even be able to be installed without installing selectr?

Comment: @Dason My guess is that an older version of `rvest` was installed that didn't have the dependency, and then maybe `update.packages()` was run to get a new version may have not got the new dependency. Or maybe there was just an error during the installation of that package. Hard to know for sure. But the error message seems pretty clear.

Comment: Thanks for the response but i do not find any package as selectr in cran. Still i am getting the same error